# Why is my image causing Chrome on Android to spawn dozens of tabs?

Tags: android, google-chrome

I'm working with a special image format and was creating something to dynamically generate it. I went to try it in mobile Chrome (it isn't displayable in the browser but it could be downloaded) and suddenly it opened about fifty new tabs! I fought with my browser to close them all but it just kept creating more.

http://www.sudomemo.net/images/dynamic/profile/540417_0BC7C6632064B_047.ntft

There are no redirects, no scripts. It's an image.

Any clue as to why this is happening? Have I discovered a Chrome bug?

```
Google Chrome 39.0.2171.93 (Official Build) 
Revision    bec62c44cbc7da9f6a507873382ebc111d66e9d7-refs/branch-heads/2171@{#449}
OS          Android 4.4.2; XT1031 Build/KXB20.9-1.10-2.27
```

Steps to reproduce: Tested on Android Kit Kat, with the only installed browser being Google Chrome.

Open Chrome and go to the above link.

Comment: Mobile Chrome? What version on what OS? You'll probably get better answers if you edit your question to specify those details.

Comment: Found out part of the issue; has to do with the Android bit. I'll write up an answer after my next class. It's rather simple, but quite interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out a while ago.

To make it short, mobile Chrome didn't know how to handle the file, as it had a text/HTML content type but wasn't parsable as text or HTML. It got passed to the Android Content Provider, (that bit which gives you options between which apps you can use to open something), which immediately returned it to Chrome, as it's the only browser on my phone, opening it in a new tab. This looped over and over, quickly causing my phone to slow down and crash.